# AWS Cross region XRay trace

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have a Lambda function that is deployed in a region and a API Gateway that is deployed in a different region. The Lambda function calls the API Gateway to make some requests. And for both regions, XRay traces are used.

Is it possible to visualize the entire XRay trace where the API Gateway is deployed, including the Lambda function as a "entry point"? I want to join both traces in one place.

Looking for this FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/xray/faqs/, AWS says:

> Q: Can I use X-Ray to track requests from applications or services
> spread across multiple regions?
> Yes, you can use X-Ray to track
> requests flowing through applications or services across multiple
> regions. X-Ray data is stored locally to the processed region but with
> enough information to enable client applications to combine the data
> and provide a global view of traces. Region annotation for AWS
> services will be added automatically, however, customers will need to
> instrument custom services to add the regional annotation to make use
> of the cross-region support.

But I did not find any example on the docs about how to do this.